# SQL syntax for LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We're having an issue with SQL Server 2012 due to the lack of support for the `*=` (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`) operator.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct syntax for SQL Server 2012 for the following SQL that worked correctly on SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT 
    t7410.name, t7408.type, t7410.length, 
    t7410.status, t7410.prec, t7410.scale, 
    t7409.type 
FROM 
    dbo.syscolumns t7410, dbo.systypes t7408, 
    dbo.sysobjects t7409, dbo.sysusers t7411, 
    master.dbo.syslogins t7412 
WHERE 
    t7410.id = t7409.id 
    AND t7411.uid = t7409.uid 
    AND t7409.name = 'GENERAL'
    AND t7409.type IN ('U', 'S', 'V') 
    AND t7410.usertype *= t7408.usertype 
    AND t7412.sid = t7411.sid 
    AND t7412.name = user_name() 
ORDER BY 
    t7410.colid ASC
```

Comment: Oh my I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: They were disallowed by default in what SQL 2000?. Last time I used them was Sql Server 6.0!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style "comma-separated list of tables" style was **discontinued** with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard....

Comment: You should also be using sys.columns, sys.users, sys.types etc. These backward compatibility views that you're using now are there for backward compatibility only - and an object's uid doesn't even mean the same thing it meant the last time these views were valid (SQL Server 2000).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not write this using ANSI JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT t7410.name, t7408.type, t7410.length, 
    t7410.status, t7410.prec, t7410.scale, 
    t7409.type 
FROM dbo.syscolumns t7410
INNER JOIN dbo.sysobjects t7409
    ON t7410.id = t7409.id
INNER JOIN dbo.sysusers t7411
    ON t7411.uid = t7409.uid 
INNER JOIN master.dbo.syslogins t7412 
    ON t7412.sid = t7411.sid 
LEFT JOIN dbo.systypes t7408
    ON t7410.usertype = t7408.usertype 
WHERE t7409.name = 'GENERAL'
    AND t7409.type IN ('U', 'S', 'V') 
    AND t7412.name = user_name() 
ORDER BY t7410.colid ASC
```

Comment: plus, you could also move the WHERE conditions into the respective JOIN clauses to avoid superfluous records that would later be eliminated by the WHERE

Comment: @devio agreed, I was just attempting to get it into ansi syntax.

Comment: @devio I think that the filter condition should go on the `WHERE` for clarity. And when you say that if they are changed on the `JOIN` condition it will avoid superfluous records, the optimizer most likely would execute the same plan for both querys. Oh, and congrats for developing Oracle! ;-)